# query using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables

`table_1`

| number | type | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | steve |
| 12 | 2 | smith |
| 12 | 2 | jack |

and so on....

similiarly for

`table_2`

| number | type | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | abraham |
| 12 | 2 | jack |
| 12 | 2 | smith |

Here i am doing inner join and i need output as where there is mismatch in name when number and type is equal. My query is

```
select * from table1,table2 
where table1.number=table2.number and table1.type=table2.type and table1.name <> table2.name
```

expected output:

| number | type | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | abraham |

and not from type '2'

But the output shows for type '2' smith jack and jack smith as well which i dont want as there is data named jack,smith for type 2 in both tables.Expected output is only for type '1' as there is mismatch can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . you can use `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.number = t1.number and t2.type = t1.type
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a subquery to compare the data between table_1 and table_2. However, I'm not sure about your table size & the index that you have in those tables. Please be careful when using this query because it is an expensive query.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_1 t1
WHERE (t1.number, t1.type, t1.name) NOT IN (
  SELECT t2.number, t2.type, t2.name
  FROM table_2 t2
);
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a weird situation. Gordon's is probably better but here's an alternative solution:

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gh7qqxus4rw7id9ca5HsLf/0)

```sql
select * from table2
where CONCAT( cast(number as char), cast(type as char), name) NOT IN
 (SELECT CONCAT( cast(number as char), cast(type as char), name) from table1)
```

Comment: My heart sinks when I see this kind of thing :-(

Comment: Me too, @Strawberry, me too.  Go with the WHERE NOT EXISTS above.